# Reading and writing binary content in R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have to download binary files stored in PostgreSQL database as `bytea` and then work with them in R. I use `DBI` library to download the content

```
data <- dbGetQuery("select binary_content from some_table limit 1", connection)
```

next I have to work with this content. The problem is that even after reviewing SO threads (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471711/bytea-data-format-in-r-shiny)),  PostgreSQL documentation, R documentation for several functions (`writeBin`, `charToRaw`, `as.raw` etc.), multiple web pages and intensive Googling I am unable to find any hints how it can be done in R. What I want to do is to (1) download the content, (2) save it locally as individual files, (3) work with the files. No matter what I do R always saves the content as it was a long gibberish character string.

Unfortunately I am unable to provide reproducible example since I cannot share the data I am using.

Comment: If you are querying out binary content, then you will have to either save it as binary, or use a library to convert it.  If you can't share with us any information about what this binary represents, then don't expect a useful answer here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the question is how to do it and where to find information about it, as for now I am unable to read or write it.

Comment: You just told us that R `saves the content as ... a long gibberish` string.  This sounds like a binary blob.  So the problem isn't R, it is your decision about how to handle binary content.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am trying a number of different combinations how to encode the output in postgresql (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-binarystring.html) and how to write it from R but neither of them works. The content is CSV files and I'd like just to save them and work with them as with CSVs.

Comment: Let's take a step back here.  What is this content, and how was it originally written into your Postgres database?  This question is more critical than the one you actually asked.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is csv file written as `bytea` column.

Comment: How is it being encoded?

Comment: How this gibberish string looks like? Is it made just of numbers in the 0-7 range? Or by 0-9a-f characters? Is it arbitrary? Please, show us an example (maybe just reorder the characters of your actual data).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the only thing I know that it is ASCII bytea

Comment: Please update your question by showing a sample of the binary ASCII you have.  In the meantime, have a look at [this site](https://www.base64decode.org/) where you can decode base 64 online.  This is my hunch about what you have.

Comment: the bytea is read into R as a hex encoded character string.  You have to convert it.  See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50999966/2371031